# Liferay Friendly URL not recognized when parameter value includes "." (period/dot)

Tags: liferay, friendly-url, liferay-7

I have the following friendly URL route:

```
<route>
    <pattern>/version/{version}</pattern>
    <implicit-parameter name="_facesViewIdRender">/WEB-INF/views/portletViewMode.xhtml</implicit-parameter>
    <implicit-parameter name="p_p_lifecycle">0</implicit-parameter>
    <implicit-parameter name="p_p_mode">view</implicit-parameter>
    <implicit-parameter name="p_p_state">normal</implicit-parameter>
</route>
```

But when I try to navigate to the following url it doesn't work:

```
localhost:8080/web/guest/home/-/my-portlet/version/1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The default pattern Liferay uses to match parameters is `"[^/\\.]+"`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.1.0-ga1/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/StringParserFragment.java#L142-L166). This pattern excludes `"/"`, `"\"`, and `"."`. You should set a custom pattern that only excludes `"/"` and `"\"`: `"[^/\\]+"`:

```
<pattern>/version/{version:[^/\\]+}</pattern>
```